# Negative look-ahead to not match on specific *.TLDs

Tags: regex, email, regex-lookarounds

I have SMTP logs and they are broken down into fields.  I am examining the TO field and would like to only see email logs when the TO address is NOT `*.com`.  If there are multiple addresses and at least one is not `*.com`, I would like to see that as well.

My syntax works when there is only one email address, however, I am having problems when there are multiple email addresses in the TO line with one of them containing ".com" or when an address has subdomains as `mail.testnet.com`   When this occurs I would still like to see the log file if there is one entry that is NOT `*.com`.

Is there any way I can write this such that it matches if there is at least one address that is not `*.com`?

**CURRENT SYNTAX**

```
^((?!\.com).)*$
```

---

Works as intended

**FAILS** `TO: <b.smith@mail.com>`

**PASSES** `TO: <j.smith@mail.net>`

**PASSES** `TO: <j.smith@mail.net>, <c.smith@mail.org>, <d.smith@mail.tv>`

---

Does not work as intended

**FAILS** `TO: <j.smith@mail.net>, <b.smith@mail.com>, <c.smith@mail.org>, <d.smith@mail.tv>`

**PASSES** `TO: <b.smith@live.mail.com>`

**PASSES** `TO: <j.smith@mail.base.net>, <b.smith@live.mail.com>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a nested negative look ahead inside a positive look ahead:

```
^(?=.*<[\w.]+@\w+\.(?!com)\w+>).*
```

See [demo](http://rubular.com/r/D7Boxfpnig)

This says "assert there is a dot followed by something other than 'com'"

Comment: it matches when it shouldn't if the email address contains a period (<b.smith@mail.com>).  That should fail, but it passes.  Any ideas how to fix? Maybe look after the "@" ?

Comment: The only case where it should NOT match but is, is when there are only multiple .coms.  I tried <b.smith@mail.com>, <d.smith@mail.com> and it did match.

Comment: It's perfect!!  I'm going to review it line by line to study this.  Thank you for all the help!

Comment: One last thing.  I found a use case that isn't working and I was hoping you could help.  `j.smith@base.test.com`

For some reason, the extra "." after the @ are allowing it to match when I don't want it to.  Can you help me again?

Comment: @user2661503 See updated regex and demo link. Please update your question to include the new edge case.

Comment: Updated!  Thank you again Bohemian!